# Grouping together everything in a site to make it not shrink

Tags: html, css

i have completed the basic template for my site. Although i have one problem. When you make the browser to small everything starts to scrunch together. The pictures get smaller and smaller until you cant see them anymore. The text starts to all go into one line. I am not sure why this is happening. My guess is that by changing the position it should work, so that is what i did. When i did change the positioning everything on my site went crazy. Is there anyway to group everything in a site and make it all static together? I am stuck at this point so any advice would be great. Basically i would like to know how to group together my site at the center while keeping the whole thing together.

I would assume that giving you a link to my site would be more effective than a fiddle.

mytesttestwebsite.com

But here is a jsfiddleanyways

http://jsfiddle.net/4yeb5x6g/

This is the code to one of the images that shrink when you make the site smaller.

```
.image10 {
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top: 738px;
    margin-left: 478px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally not start messing with the z-index property.

From the small css code you put here isn't enough to gauge the problem. I would suggest that you enclose everything into a div with a set width

<<'div id='container' style='width:800px'>>

place website in this space

'<<'/div>>'

sorry ignore the ' i don't know how to display code yet!

Good luck, 
Boom!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, I feel that it is safe to assume you have used things like `width="50%"` or `height="100%"` or whatever.

Make sure you are using set heights, such as `width="87px"` or `height="168px"`

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked at your code and yes, you need to define a wide for the entire site, so as I said before. You must put everything in a div tag and specify a width for it in CSS or the html